# Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:] while embedding in parent controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

Scenario :

1. A view controller **ControllerA** with a collection view in it.
2. This collection view has been given a custom layout in **viewDidLoad** of Controller A : `self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = [[MyCustomFlowLayout alloc]init];`
3. If **ControllerA** is loaded onto the screen it works fine but if it is loaded inside another controller,say **ParentController** it gives an assertion error as :

> *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UICollectionViewData.m:357

I wanted to post an image but couldn't until I have 10 reputation points.

There is some problem with custom layout while embedding in a different controller. But I am not able to figure out what. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this questions is old, but I figured I'd post an answer because I ran into this issue too.  I'm using a horizontal scrolling collection view inside a vertical scrolling collection view cell.

In the View Controller:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:nil completion:^(BOOL finished)
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:kSaleSection];
        PromoFeedCollectionCell *cell = (PromoFeedCollectionCell *) [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (cell)
        {
            [cell resizeCellView];
        }
        finished = YES;
    }];
}
```

And inside my PromoFeedCollectionCell containing the collectionView:

```
- (void)resizeCellView
{
    [self setNeedsLayout];

    [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:nil completion:^(BOOL finished){

    finished = YES;
    }];
}
```